# How to create multiple instances of the same shape in HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, class, canvas

I'm trying to create a canvas with several triangles all over the place.

I would like to create a class of a path in order to instantiate it multiple times. I've tried that:

```
class Triangle {

  constructor( x = 0, y = 0 ) {

    // Get context from the global variable 'ctx'
    this.ctx = ctx;

    // Draw triangle
    this.ctx.beginPath();
      this.ctx.lineTo( 0  , 0   );
      this.ctx.lineTo( 80 , 80  );
      this.ctx.lineTo( 0  , 160 );
      this.ctx.moveTo( x  , y   );
    this.ctx.closePath();

    // Place color
    this.ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
    this.ctx.fill();
  }
}
```

Unfortunately if I do that it works just with the first element. Meaning that the result is two triangles on 0,0 position...

```
var T1 = new Triangle( 0, 0 );
var T2 = new Triangle( 10, 10 );
```

How can I create multiple triangles and reference to them singularely?

---

## EDIT

After @markE answer I updated my code [here below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38785207/1498118).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `context.translate` to offset your [0,0] triangles to any new coordinate on the canvas.

When you `translate` you're actually moving the [0,0] canvas origin to a specified [x,y]. This causes anything drawn after `translate` to be drawn with an [x,y] offset.

An added benefit of `translate` is that you don't need to modify the coordinates of your triangle -- `translate` automatically does that for you!

**Example code and a Demo:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var Triangle=( function(){
    var self;
    function Triangle(x,y,fillcolor){
        self=this;
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
        this.fillcolor=fillcolor;
    }
    Triangle.prototype.draw=function(ctx){
        // offset the [0,0] triangle to [x,y]
        ctx.translate(this.x,this.y);
        // Define triangle
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineTo( 0  , 0   );
        ctx.lineTo( 80 , 80  );
        ctx.lineTo( 0  , 160 );
        ctx.closePath();
        // fill triangle
        ctx.fillStyle = this.fillcolor;
        ctx.fill();
        // always clean up! Undo the translation    
        ctx.translate(-this.x,-this.y);
    };
    return(Triangle);
})();

// create new triangles, but don't draw them yet
var T1=new Triangle(0,0,'gold');
var T2=new Triangle(150,30,'red');
var T3=new Triangle(300,60,'green');

// draw the triangles onto the canvas
T1.draw(ctx);
T2.draw(ctx);
T3.draw(ctx);
```

```css
body{ background-color:white; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=512 height=512></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

After @markE [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38775148/1498118) I updated my code this way, just to clean it up a bit. I also followed [Kaiido comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38773977/how-to-create-multiple-instances-of-the-same-shape-in-html-canvas/38785207?noredirect=1#comment64941152_38785207) in order to improve performances.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx    = canvas.getContext('2d');

//------------------------------
// TRIANGLE SETUP

class Triangle {

  constructor( x = 0, y = 0, fillColor = '#000' ) {
    // Settings
    this.x   = x;
    this.y   = y;
    this.fillColor = fillColor;
    // Setup everything once parameters are setup
    this.setup();
  }

  setup() {
    // Move context to position
    ctx.translate( this.x, this.y );
    // Draw from new context position
    this.draw();
    // Restore context back to initial position
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  }

  draw() {
    // Draw triangle
    ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.lineTo(   0,   0   );
      ctx.lineTo(   80,  80  );
      ctx.lineTo(   0,   160 );
    ctx.closePath();
    // Fill color
    ctx.fillStyle = this.fillColor;
    ctx.fill();
  }
}

// Create Triangle instances
var T1 = new Triangle( 160, 20 );
var T2 = new Triangle( 20, 80, 'red' );
```

```css
#canvas { background-color: #EEE; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=512 height=512></canvas>
```

Comment: be carefull with `ctx.save()`and `ctx.restore()`, these will save all the properties of your context (`fillStyle`, `strokeStyle`, `clip`, `transforms`, `fonts`, `gCO`, etc.) This can be very heavy and should be avoided as much as possible. If you just need to reset your transform matrix to its original state, simply call `ctx.setTranform(1,0,0,1,0,0)` which is even better than the minus previous transfrom by @markE, since in js everything is float and that you may not end on the same point after a lot of these ops.

Comment: Thank you @Kaiido for the improvement. I also cleaned up code a bit more.