# Canvas JavaScript HTML --Creating several occurrences from one parent

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am initializing classes like so (Character is a class in my program):

```
character = new Character();
```

I want two instances of this class/object, so I tried this:

```
character2 = new Character();
```

Yet character2 simply replaces character; therefore, there is only one object. Is it possible to create another instance, or would I need to make another Character class (a lot of code duplication!).

I tried adding a second draw function (named draw2, for the second object), but  that didn't help.

Comment: Your code is correct, there are 2 separate instances. Why do you think they replace each other?

Comment: In my program, the 2nd instance is definitely replacing the 1st. Strange. I can't understand why. The 1st instance completely disappears (isn't visible) at runtime.

Comment: Please share Character class.

Comment: Hi Emil. I have added the Character class into the main post. Thanks.

Comment: If anyone has any idea, please help. This is giving me nightmares.

Comment: Right now there are some basic errors: where is `imageObj` defined? img is never used and not handled properly (async), prototype is defined inside the object itself (there is missing an end-bracket which could explain this)... you can also make the code more readable by replacing Object.defineProperty with simple properties directly as nothing is actually done to the value besides from read/write.

Comment: Hi. Thank for your reply. imageObj should read img. Oops. I'll edit that now. I'll try to understand everything else you've said and get back to you. Many thanks!

Comment: I apologize profusely to the people who have attempted to help, but I still have no idea why I can't draw a second instance without it replacing the first. It's crazy; I'm certainly pulling my hair out! Nevertheless I'm stubbornly trying to resolve this issue. I found this but it doesn't work for me (same issue, replaces 1st object): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38773977/how-to-create-multiple-instances-of-the-same-shape-in-html-canvas/38785207?noredirect=1

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the definition of the `Character.prototype.draw` method out of the constructor function. Otherwise, each time you create a `new Character()`, you also override the `Character.prototype.draw` method.

You also need to replace references to local constructor function variables within the `Character.prototype.draw` method such as `x`, `y` or `size` with object properties such as `this.X`, `this.Y` and `this.Size`.

Also, you need to make the `img` a (possibly static) property of your `Character`.

Answer (score 0):

## Object creation in modern JS

Modern JS includes some shortcuts when defining objects. There is no real need to use prototype unless you are creating many instances of the Object. Accessing the prototype adds some overhead when using objects

You can create the object inside the creating function that allows you to define private properties via closure.

#### Closure creates private properties

```
function Character() {
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var size = 25;
    var vx = 4;
    var vy = 4;
    var width = 45;
    var height = 45;
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'character.jpg';
    var pattern;
    // using API = {rather than return {  allows you to access the instance of the
    // inside this scope without having to use the `this` token
    const API = {
        get x() { return x },
        get y() { return y },
        get vx() { return vx },
        get vy() { return vy },
        get size() { return size },
        get width() { return width },
        get height() { return height },
        set x(v) { x = v },
        set y(v) { y = v },
        set vx(v) { vx = v },
        set vy(v) { vy = v },
        set size(v) { size = v },
        set width(v) { width = v },
        set height(v) { height = v },
        draw(ctx) {
            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(x, y);
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            ctx.fillStyle = pattern ? pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, "no-repeat") : pattern;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(-size, -size);
            ctx.lineTo(-size, size);
            ctx.lineTo(size, size);
            ctx.lineTo(size, -size);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.restore();
        },
    }
    return API;
}
```

usage

```
var char = Character();
var char1 = Character();
// or 

var char = new Character();
var char1 = new Character();
```

#### Performance considerations

If the object is required in performance code you may want to create more performant setters and getters, or avoid the getter setter overhead and include the properties in the object itself.

```
function Character() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = 'character.jpg';
    var pattern;
    // using API = {rather than return {  allows you to access the instance of the
    // inside this scope without having to use the `this` token
    const API = {
        x : 0, 
        y : 0,
        size : 25,
        vx : 4,
        vy : 4,
        width : 45,
        height : 45,
        draw(ctx) {
            const size = API.size;
            ctx.save();
            ctx.translate(API.x, API.y); // Note that I use API.x rather than this.x
            ctx.lineWidth = 2;
            ctx.fillStyle = pattern ? pattern = ctx.createPattern(img, "no-repeat") : pattern;
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(-size, -size);
            ctx.lineTo(-size, size);
            ctx.lineTo(size, size);
            ctx.lineTo(size, -size);
            ctx.closePath();
            ctx.fill();
            ctx.stroke();
            ctx.restore();
        },
    }
    return API;
}
```

#### Notes.

I noticed you have way too many comments.

eg

```
//public property for VX
Object.defineProperty(this, 'width',
```

and

```
//function public draw method
Character.prototype.draw = function (ctx) {
    //save the ctx
    ctx.save();
    //set x and y
    ctx.translate(x, y);
    //set the line width
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
```

You are stating the obvious in a comment, no machine will read it, no human needs to read it, so why is it there. Comments add noise, and source code noise is dangerous, avoid all unnecessary noise in your code.

---

You create the pattern each time the draw function is called, this is unneeded overhead. Create it only once.

---

There is a time when calling the draw function may not work as the image will not have loaded yet. Maybe you should manage images outside the object where you can ensure that media objects are loaded and ready to be used befor you try to use them.

---

Each instance of `Character` will load the image, create 100 of them and there will be 100 copies of the **same** image. This will affect performance and memory negatively.